# Unable to make a sql query to get week ago's data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a SQL to get the Number of impressions and clicks from the click_table by the pub_name from the publish_table in the last 7 days. How can I write it ?

I tried to write the query but I feel that something is not right. How to make the above condition in SQL? I would love to hear from you.

```
SELECT Impressions, Clicks
FROM click_table
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() by area;
```

Comment: Can you post your `click_table` table DDL?

Comment: *Number of impressions and clicks* Use COUNT(). *by area* Add proper GROUP BY.

Comment: It Should Work in SQL SERVER:
SELECT Impressions, Clicks
FROM click_table WHERE date >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
order by area

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for aggregation:

```
SELECT area, SUM(Impressions), SUM(Clicks)
FROM click_table
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY area;
```

I am guessing that you don't have future dates, so this should be sufficient.

Comment: What if I wanted the Number of impressions and clicks from the click_table by the pub_name from the publish_table in the last 7 days. How can I write it ? I updated the question. I would love to hear from you!

Comment: @Jennifer . . . You should ask a NEW question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.